# How to debug geolocation provider issues?

Tags: settings, networking

I cant get any geolocation on my elementary notebook. At first, I was trying to get the location when testing a mapping website using the Browser Geolocation API. Firefox and Chromium cant get any result from the Systems Geolocation Service. Then I tested with Gnome Maps, and it did not work either. As far as I know, Ubuntu based distros use geoclue and its providers for that, but it does not seem to work. How can I configure and debug it in elementary? I dont have a GPS on the notebook, but there should be at least a City-level result from the network/IP based location provider. I did not test with other OSes, but on different fixed WiFi networks. I am aware there is a settings page in elementary where I can allow/disallow apps to use the location provider, but Firefox and other browsers are not registered and I also can't add any new program manually.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me.

Add to /etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf:

[redshift]
allowed=true
system=false
users=